# session problem in php between two panels

Tags: php

hy I have created two panels first is members panel and second is admin panel. In these two panels, I have created a session file in those panels.

but when I logged in into members panel and without log out from this panel, I go to admin panel it does not ask any username or password it's taken me to direct index page.

members panel :

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();

$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select email from outlet where email = '$user_check' ");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_session = $row['email'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
  header("location:login.php");
}
 ?>
```

Admin Panel :

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();

$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select email from admin where email = '$user_check' ");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_session = $row['email'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
  header("location:login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: From your code it seems that you have a user with the same email in both `outlet` and `admin` tables and you are comparing it with the values in your `$_SESSION`. Which it would than pass because it has the correct value. You will need to store additional data in your sessions. Such as `isAdminLoggedin` and/or `isOutletLoggedin` or something similar that you will than also compare along with the email.

Comment: i have different email stored in admin tabel and outlet table

Answer (score 0):

You need to store admin or member flag in a session. And them apply condition on it

```
if($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'admin') {
    header('location:admin.php');
} else {
    header('location:member.php');
}
```